# Auto Email Send from outlook using excel information from the cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need to send auto email from Excel using Excel Outlook, I was trying coding but unable to do it. I have attached sheet for your reference.

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "ABC@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Report"
    .Body = "Hello!"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "SendEmail"

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference and login into the Outlook.Namespace before creating the email.

Try adding this to to your code:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'** -> add this block here
Dim OutNS as Object
Set OutNS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
OutNS.Logon
'**

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Comment: If I send from gmail

Comment: message should go as per the cell values

Comment: @NagarajShet - `If I send from gmail` - What do you mean with this? You never mentioned anything about gmail in your original post. Please clarify your question and I will update or delete my answer as necessary.